# not able to connect to server on internet

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, network-protocols

I have a very simple client server code written java(server listens on some port and client connects to server port and after connection is established, client ip is displayed on server console). This program is working very well in intranet, but if client and server are on internet, my server cannot detect it.I have no firewall installed on my client and server and port forwarding is done on server(I can see it from canyouseeme.org).

Server is directly connected to modem along with other three computers(they are also connected to modem directly)

Please help me figure out why I am not able to detect client on internet.Thanks in advance.

```
Client code:
------------

String remoteIP = //remote ip
int port =1888;

try{
new Socket(remoteIp,port);
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e.message());
}

Server code
-----------
ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
displayIp(socket);
```

Comment: Please post the code of this 'very simple client server code'.

Comment: What do you mean by 'if client and server are on internet, my server cannot detect it'? Can the client connect to the server in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your proxy configurations on the client side, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Which protocol do you use?

Comment: I use TCP protocol(using java sockets). But the thing is only server on my system is not detecting client. If I run server on my office system(which is directly connected to modem, it is able to detect client).So it must be some problem on my server. But I am able to see my server on canyouseeme.org

Comment: Try to change your code to port 80, also on WAN router with NAT where server is connected. Check server again from canyouseeme.org on port 80. Then open browser in client and go to e.g. http: //www.google.com, then goto http://<your-server-ip> . This *must* work.